# outlook or mail server with whitelist for sending and receiving

Tags: microsoft-outlook, mail-server

I work at a Community House (Robinson Reserve Neighbourhood House - RRNH) teaching computer classes, and we would like to teach Outlook.  Our reason for not yet having the computer's Outlook setup is that we wouldn't want the general public just mailing out to everyone from the RRNH account. Probably more fearful than need be.

How would I go about setting up ~10 email accounts so that they can only send and receive to each other?

- A free way would be the best
- We have an existing domain and shared hosting
- Spending a small quantity of money on more basic hosting and another domain might also be OK

Thank you for your collective wisdom

Answer (score 0):

Email doesn't have to be public. You could limit a mail experiment quite easily by simply blocking TCP port 25 (the port used for SMTP). Make sure you know the ports used by the mail server you select.

Spin up a copy of [Ubuntu server and give postfix](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto) a whirl. I'd love to break the entire process down for you, but you've got a lot of reading ahead of you anyway.

Don't worry about a domain name. Use some fake name that won't be routable outside your network, like `example.bogus` or something.